# adding a html tag around a specific content in Python

Tags: python

I have a html content like:
 `<span style="font-family: times new roman,times; font-size: 12pt;">Patient Name: &lt;&lt;Member_Name&gt;&gt;</span>`.
Now, i want to add a tag around:
`&lt;&lt;Member_Name&gt;&gt`
like:
`<span class = "read-only">`
and close it after:
 `&lt;&lt;Member_Name&gt;&gt` using **Python**.
The reason is i am adding some styles for the class 'read-only'.
Can anyone please give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use any render template like Jinja, you could treat it as a variable arounded by `{{ my_str }}`, then you should generate some tag you want and assign it to variable `my_str`.

Do it with beautiful soup, as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
obj = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html5lib)
# find the tag you need
t = find('xxx')
t.insert(0, '<span class="readonly">')
t.insert(len(t.text), '</span>')
```

Maybe it works

Comment: Thanks for the response.Is it not possible to achieve it using parsers like Lxml or Beautiful Soup?

Comment: I've append the way using beautifulsoup